# Register new user based on his department using Filament Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I hope you're all doing well. I'm currently working on a project and could use some guidance and expertise to help me implement a user registration system with department-based access. I have three different panels: 'hr', 'finance', and 'property,' each with its respective logins. My goal is to allow a superadmin to register new users with their email, password, and department. When a registered user logs in, they should be directed to their designated department panel.

I could not find a better documentation